# How to create text next to a picture

Tags: adobe-brackets

[enter link description here](http://file:///Users/YoungBot911/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202018-09-10%20at%2010.30.47%20AM.png)I'm doing this

Nothing seems to be working i'm trying to place this next to that image and it doesn't work please help!

```
        <div>
             <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/ebaumsworld.prod/uploads1517445898749-old-school-Runescape-mobile-2.jpg" width=500px/>
<p>
Players ALWAYS need food. Skip cooking a lot of other foods and just level yourself up to the point that you can cook fish. Save all fish lower than lobsters for yourself, and when you are able to cook and catch lobsters, do NOTHING ELSE for several days. Before you know it, you will be able to catch and cook swordfish. Sell lobsters and swordfish and keep a few for yourself. Whenever you get up to the point that you can catch and cook sharks, your fortune is made. They sell for at least 1k each.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can float your image with a CSS property.

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

p.offset {
  margin-left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x150" />
  <p class='offset'>

    Players ALWAYS need food. Skip cooking a lot of other foods and just level yourself up to the point that you can cook fish. Save all fish lower than lobsters for yourself, and when you are able to cook and catch lobsters, do NOTHING ELSE for several days.
    Before you know it, you will be able to catch and cook swordfish. Sell lobsters and swordfish and keep a few for yourself. Whenever you get up to the point that you can catch and cook sharks, your fortune is made. They sell for at least 1k each.
  </p>
```

Comment: Yes this does work but now the rest of my work also goes next to the picture? How do I place the other text underneath the image apart from the text you see in my question. [link] (file:///Users/YoungBot911/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202018-09-10%20at%2010.30.47%20AM.png) I Think the image is there??

Comment: No its not there um how do I put an image in this comment??

Comment: So basically you want the text as a column next to the picture?

Comment: I changed it around for you a bit, so it ends up in a column, instead of folding around the image.

Comment: Thanks dude this helps soooo much :D

Comment: Welcome to SO ..  After your question has been answered you may "accept" the answer and with that close it. Happy coding!